# Implementing O365 license management across Parent and SubDomains

Tags: domain, subdomain, microsoft-office-365, office365

*I've also posted this to SuperUser if we find it's not relevant to ServerFault*

**Alternate title where the answer is possibly less subjective.**

**In the event of our Credit Card expiring/becoming compromised, how can we set up our O365 to avoid having to update the billing info in each "sub"domain?**

Background info:

We provide part of the MS Office stack to our clients. Some clients do not want to set up or, do not already have an active O365 implementation. In that case, we purchase a domain and stand up a new domain in our Azure with our 'God user' ( DOMAIN_DEMON@OurRootDomain.com ) account. Once the new domain is validated, we create an admin user that we only have access to on that domain ( Service_Admin@"Sub"Domain.com ). These new domains are what I refer to as "Sub"Domains.

We then login to the O365 portal for the new domain, purchase licenses with the Service_Admin on our CC, list ourselves as Partners of Record and then assign them to users for our client.

This works well for compartmentalization and allows for maximum control on our part, but I'm becoming concerned that when it comes time to update the CC, it's gonna take 2 days to do so across all our subdomains.

**Question:**

In the event of our Credit Card expiring/becoming compromised, how can we set up our O365 to avoid having to update the billing info in each "sub"domain? Is there a better way to manage these 300+ licenses across all these "sub"domains?

Answer (score 2):

Register yourself as a Microsoft Partner. The easiest way to do this is with a MAP (Microsoft Action Pack) Subscription. That way you can establish a reseller relationship between you and your 'subdomains'. Microsoft will send you a one bill for all the subscription you offer.

Bonus: You get a cut of the sale.

If you are unable to register as a Partner, you can always use another reseller who provides a portal where you can do this yourself, you will be billed by them. It's pretty common for you to also receive a cut of the sale, albeit less than when you would be a MS Partner yourself.